# How to break down 404 URLs into single words and search for them?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on my Page not found 404 template. For some reason my conditional doesn't seem to work right:

What I am trying to achieve is to break down the path and search for each expression.
I remove - and _ from the expression.

```
$s = preg_replace("/(.*)-(html|htm|php|asp|aspx)$/","$1",$wp_query->query_vars['name']);
            $posts = query_posts('post_type=any&name='.$s);
            $s = str_replace("-"," ",$s);
            $s = str_replace("_"," ",$s);
            if (count($posts) == 0) {
                $posts = query_posts('post_type=any&s='.$s);
            }
            if (count($posts) > 0) {
                echo "<ol><li>";
                echo "<p>Were you looking for <strong>one of the following</strong> posts or pages?</p>";               
                echo "<ul>";
                foreach ($posts as $post) {
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
                }
                echo "</ul>";
}
```

If I type "products_s"

It says:

> in Let me help you find what you came here for: Were you looking for
>   one of the following posts or pages? 
>   **Products**

So It finds products, which is great.

But if i type in "products_services"

Even though I am expecting to get products and services pages listed as above, it doesn't finds anything.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used wordpress but I do notice you change the `queryposts()`

In the first check you do:

`$posts = query_posts('post_type=any&name='.$s); //notice &name=`

In the second check you do:

`$posts = query_posts('post_type=any&s='.$s); // notice &s=`

It all depends what is happening inside of `queryposts()`. Personally I would just pass the string through with '_' '-' and `explode('-',$string)` on the other side to split them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working for you is because Wordpress's search only returns posts that meet all the words in the query. So, "products_s" turns into "products s" and both "products" and "s" are in the word Products. So Products gets returned. "products_ducts" would return the same page.

If you had a page named Products and Services, you'd get a result with your second search.

Perhaps you could split the string at the spaces and perform a search for each word and append the results to each other.